# Recover previous Python output to terminal

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, logging

I have a bash script, in Python that runs on a Ubuntu server. Today, I mistakenly closed the Putty window after monitoring that the script ran correctly.

There is some usefull information that was printed during the scrip running and I would like to recover them.

**Is there a directory**, like /var/log/syslog for system logs, **for Python logs?**

- This scripts takes 24 hours to run, on a very costly AWS EC2 instance, and running it again is not an option.
- Yes, I should have printed usefull information to a log file myself, from the python script, but no, I did not do that.

Comment: No. The script's output was obviously written to `/dev/stdout` respectively `/dev/stderr`. If you did not explicitely log the script's output using e.g. `tee`, your output will be gone for good.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: See however if the script code uses the `logging` module.

Comment: Could you clarify?

Comment: Well, python programs can choose to log their output to files for example, or any information they want. They usually do it by using the builtin `logging` module. If you see `import logging` or `from logging import` in your script, may be something was logged.

Comment: There was nothing like that. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardNeumann if you want to write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the script has an internal logging mechanism like e.g. using `logging` as mentioned in the comments, the output will have been written to `/dev/stdout` or `/dev/stderr` respectively, in which case, if you did not log the respective data streams to a file for persistent storage by using e.g. `tee`, your output is lost.